# Mysql prints help instead of connecting to server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL server:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql.exe -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h www.example.net DB_NAME
```

The result:

```
mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql.exe [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.


... and so on, the help page is long.
```

Why does the `mysql.exe` utility ignore my commands?

Comment: Have you tried `mysql.exe -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h www.example.net DB_NAME`? Password without space after -p.

Comment: @KaranPunamiya Thanks it works. But isn't that weird that only password has no space?

Comment: It might be surprising, but at least it's clearly stated in the documentation (`man mysql`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password must have no space before it:

```
mysql.exe -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD
```